# Minimum operations for making an array alternating in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I have been solving [this leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-operations-to-make-the-array-alternating/) problem and my code doesn't work when a large list is passed.

I have counted manually too and it seems to be correct but the expected answer is slightly different.

```py
def minimumOperations(nums):
    counter = 0
    
    if len(nums) == 1 or len(nums) == 2:
        return 0
    # print(len(nums) - 1)
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
    
        if (i != (len(nums) - 2)):
            if ((nums[i] != nums[i + 2])):
                nums[i + 2] = nums[i]
                # print(i, "List at that index ", nums)
                counter += 1
        if (i == (
                len(nums) - 2)):  # Checking if i is the second last position of the list in order to compare and increment the counter
            if (nums[i - 1] != nums[i + 1]):
                nums[i + 1] = nums[i - 1]
                counter += 1
            # counter += 1
    return counter
```

It works fine when I pass `nums = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` as the input since the output for this is `2` and I get it correctly via my code but when I pass

```
nums = [69, 91, 47, 74, 75, 94, 22, 100, 43, 50, 82, 47, 40, 51, 90, 27, 98, 85, 47, 14, 55, 82, 52, 9, 65, 90, 86, 45,
        52, 52,
        95, 40, 85, 3, 46, 77, 16, 59, 32, 22, 41, 87, 89, 78, 59, 78, 34, 26, 71, 9, 82, 68, 80, 74, 100, 6, 10, 53,
        84, 80,
        7, 87, 3, 82, 26, 26, 14, 37, 26, 58, 96, 73, 41, 2, 79, 43, 56, 74, 30, 71, 6, 100, 72, 93, 83, 40, 28, 79, 24]
```

I get the output as `87` which is correct if I count it manually but the expected answer is `84`. I am not sure if I am missing some validation case here / if there is some understanding gap?

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The logic you're using to solve the problem is incorrect.

You are finding the *first* elements at an even and odd indexes and you count how many changes you have to do to make all the elements at even indexes be the same as the former and all the elements at odd indexes be the same as the latter.

For your large list `nums` what you actually do is that you find `69` at index `0` and `91` at index `1` and you modify `nums` to become:

```py
[69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69, 91, 69]
```

Given that `nums` has `89` elements and each of `69` and `91` appears only *once* in `nums`, the number of changes that you have to do to get the result above is `87`, which is what your function returns.

The above sentence hints to the correct logic for solving the problem. Instead of the *first* elements at an even and odd indexes you need the *most frequent* ones.

For your large list `nums`, those are `47` (even indexes) and `74` (odd indexes) with frequencies, `2` and `3`, respectively. Thus, the minimum changes that you have to do are `89-2-3=84`, which is the expected answer.

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> Counter(nums[::2]).most_common(1) # even indexes
[(47, 2)]
>>>
>>> Counter(nums[1::2]).most_common(1) # odd indexes
[(74, 3)]
```

To get to a correct solution, you have to take care of the case when the most frequent elements at the even and odd indexes are the same. In that case, you should look for the next most frequent elements. Intuitively, you only need to look at the two most frequent elements at even and odd indexes.

Below is a working solution that uses a running `min` for the number of operations and considers the possibilities for the most frequent values at the even and odd indexes:

```py
class Solution:
    def minimumOperations(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return 0
        
        freq_even_idx = Counter(nums[::2]).most_common(2) # two most frequent, even indexes
        freq_odd_idx = Counter(nums[1::2]).most_common(2) # two most frequent, odd indexes
        
        min_ops_so_far, len_nums = float('inf'), len(nums) 
        for (even_val, even_freq) in freq_even_idx:
            for (odd_val, odd_freq) in freq_odd_idx:
                ops = len_nums-even_freq if even_val == odd_val else len_nums-even_freq-odd_freq
                min_ops_so_far = min(ops,min_ops_so_far)
        return min_ops_so_far
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give me a walkthrough of your snippet?